# My project Ruby On Rails cannot install gem postgre in CentOS 6.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, centos

Although many sources of references from stackoverflow but my problem has not been resolved. When I run My project (ProjectJapanFull_New) on window server it no problem, but when I switched it to CentOS server 6.2 is an error, namely:

```
[root@links02 ProjectJapanFull_New]# rails -v
You have requested:
  pg >= 0

The bundle currently has pg locked at 0.17.0.
Try running `bundle update pg`
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then I run: `bundle install` another error show:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/pg-0.17.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When i run `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` show this error:

```
[root@links02 ProjectJapanFull_New]# gem install pg -v '0.17.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/pg-0.17.0/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Try giving this command `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

Comment: If that doesn't work.. try this `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config`

Comment: @Pavan, it's CENTOS, so probably `sudo yum install libpq-dev`

Comment: @RubyRacer Yup! You are right.

Comment: Thank you all. I have try this but it not work, And when I try new project : '$ rails new myapp --database=postgresql' => `Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem `, But i can't run ` `yum install postgresql-devel`,

Comment: Centos - sudo yum install libpq-dev  returns "No package libpq-dev available."  postgresql-devel is already installed, but the "Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
" error persists.  The yum provides command says libpq is found in postgresql-libs, but this is also already installed.  Why does fixing this problem seem change every few months, making my last "how to install" notes worthless?